# PHP Image not uploaded to website

Tags: php

On my website I have 2 separate places for users to upload an image.  The first works perfectly.  The second doesn't.  As far as I can see, they are exactly the same.  To test, I used the same image on both, with it working on the first, but not the second.  Here is the code from the non-working one:

```
<?php
include('cn.php');

$name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$error = $_FILES['image']['error'];

echo $name; //Doesnt echo anything

$rand_num = rand(1, 1000000000);

$name = $rand_num . "_" . $name;

echo $name; //Echos just the random number followed by _

if ($error > 0) { 
    die("Error uploading file! Go back to the <a href='gallery.php'>gallery</a> page and try again.");
} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO gallery (image) VALUES ('".$name."')"; //Inserts the random number to the database
    $query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    echo $sql; 

    move_uploaded_file($temp, "gallery_pics/$name"); //Doesn't move the file.  gallery_pics exists, if that matters
    echo "Upload complete! Go back to the <a href='gallery.php'>album</a>.";
}

?>
```

If someone could please help me out here.  I am sure it is something simple, but I have yet to find anything that helped.  Thanks!

EDIT: There are two lines above the code that won't show up properly.  One starts the php and the other opens the database.

Comment: Both places are on the same server ?

Comment: Could you put your HTML code up please?

Comment: Both move files to gallery_pics ? Check the permissions on that folder.

Comment: are u posting to this page itself?

Comment: The first actually moves it to user_pics.. That could be the problem.. I'll check it out.

Comment: Try printing the FILES Array print_r($_FILES);

Comment: You should be checking for the error code in `$_FILES['image']['error']` before doing anything. inc setting your variables from the `$_FILES['image']` array

Answer (score 0):

Do both scripts reside in the same directory? If not, make sure you specify proper relative or a full path, preceded by slash like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($temp, "/some_folder/gallery_pics/$name");
```

Also, do you check the extensions of uploaded files? If not, the user could upload and execute a PHP file, for example. And by the way, your file name would look better this way:

```
$rand_num = rand(1111111111, 9999999999);
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable error reporting when developing or trying to find a fault also check your server error logs. Check for the `$_FILES['image']['error']` error code and display the error accordingly. Have a go with the code below. hope it helps

```
<?php
//Enable error reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$error_types = array(
    0=>"There is no error, the file uploaded with success",
    1=>"The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini",
    2=>"The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form",
    3=>"The uploaded file was only partially uploaded",
    4=>"No file was uploaded",
    6=>"Missing a temporary folder"
);

if($_FILES['image']['error']==0) {
    // process
    $name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
    $size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    //mt_rand() = 0-RAND_MAX and make filename safe.
    $name = mt_rand()."_".preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]/s', '_', $name);

    //insert into db, swich to PDO
    ...

    //Move file upload
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], "gallery_pics/$name")) {
        echo "Upload complete! Go back to the <a href='gallery.php'>album</a>.";
    } else {
        echo "Failed to move uploaded file, check server logs!\n";
    }
} else {
    // error
    $error_message = $error_types[$_FILES['userfile']['error']];
    die("Error uploading file! ($error_message)<br/>Go back to the <a href='gallery.php'>gallery</a> page and try again.");
}
?>
```